# When I run the program, It says the variable result is not defined. This is in Applescript

Tags: applescript

```
set var to "Which Application would you like to open?"
display dialog var buttons {"Cancel", "Safari", "Calculator"}
if button returned of result is "Calculator" then
    display dialog "Are you sure?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
    if button returned of result is "Yes" then
        tell application "Mail" to activate

    end if
else
    display dialog "Are you sure?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
    if button returned of result is "Yes" then
        tell application "Safari" to activate
    end if
    if button returned of result is "Cancel" then
        return
    end if

end if
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` only refers to the line above it. You need to store it as another variable if you wanna use it later.

```
set TheResult to button returned of result
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try and format your code in this forum a little better to assist people trying to help you. You don't need the last "Cancel" option and you also are asking the user if they want to launch "Calculator" but then you launch "Mail".  I've made some modifications to your code and reposted it.

```
set var to "Which Application would you like to open?"
display dialog var buttons {"Cancel", "Safari", "Calculator"}
if button returned of result is "Calculator" then
        display dialog "Are you sure?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
    if button returned of result is "Yes" then
        tell application "Calculator" to activate
    end if
else
    display dialog "Are you sure?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2
    if button returned of result is "Yes" then
        tell application "Safari" to activate
    end if
end if
```